# Exact differential equation, critical idea

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone show me the proof of this equality.

note: this equality is critical to the idea of the exact differential equation.

((∂f (x,y)/∂x)×dx)+((∂f (x,y)/∂y)×dy)=df (x,y)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$f(x+h,y+g)-f(x,y)=(f(x+h,y+g)-f(x,y+g))+(f(x,y+g)-f(x,y))\\
\approx\left.h\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{(x,y+g)}+\left.g\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right|_{(x,y)}.$$